# Redirect URL from MVC model to usual form

Tags: php, windows, iis

I have a website in PHP format on Godaddy windows Host. My map of directory is like bellow:

- Controller

  - Admin

    - indexAdmin.php
  - Public

    - index.php
- Model
- Public
- View

My public URL is like:

```
www.mydomain.com/Controller/Public/index.php
```

and for login via admin page the URL is like:

```
www.mydomain.com/Controller/Admin/indexAdmin.php
```

Therefore, I want to remove directories and redirect URLs like bellow when users request them:

1. From `www.domain.com` **TO** `www.mydomain.com/Controller/Public/index.php`
   (in other words, when users type *www.domain.com* display *index.php* page in public folder with *www.domain.com* in URL)
2. `www.domain.com/indexAdmin` **TO** `www.mydomain.com/Controller/Admin/indexAdmin.php`
   (when users type *www.domain.com/indexAdmin* display *indexAdmin.php* page in Admin Folder with *www.domain.com/indexAdmin* in URL)

Comment: u need to use htaccess to achieve your point, please read htaccess rules